# Cirq: How to change `atol` in `validate_density_matrix` when using `DensityMatrixSimulator`

Tags: cirq

I have a code that essentially looks like this

```
# Density matrix simulator
    sim = cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator(
    split_untangled_states=True
)

# Simulate
result = sim.simulate(
    circuit,
    resolver,
    initial_state=rho,
    qubit_order=cirq.LineQubit.range(num_q)
)
```

My initial state `rho` is a density matrix. However, `cirq.validate_density_matrix(rho)` raises value error "The density matrix is not positive semidefinite.", but changing the default value of `atol` from 1e-7 to 1e-6 removes this value error. Therefore I would like to tell `DensityMatrixSimulator` to use `atol` of 1e-6 when simulating the circuit. How can I do that?

Comment: A quick glance indicates there's no way to do it at the moment. I'd recommend opening an issue to get it fixed https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues . As a workaround in the meantime you could write a method to numerically project your density matrix closer to the valid subspace.

Comment: Thanks! I will follow your advice.